# View Job Properties Fails for Job Owner

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Domain user `MyDomain\UserA` has a login with a server role of `public` and is a user of the `msdb` database with membership in the `SQLAgentUserRole`.

The user owns a job, `Daily Job`. When logged in as the user, if I try to view the job properties, I get this error:

> Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "guest" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission. (Microsoft Server, Error: 15517)

If I right click on `Jobs` and Select `New Job...` I get the exact same error.

I have even given the user membership in `SQLAgentOperatorRole` but get the same error.

In all my searching online, the only similar issue I've found is [this question on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0ffbe3c9-661b-471a-a028-1034b3f7413a/user-cannot-create-sql-agent-job?forum=sqlsecurity), which is unanswered.

Any ideas? I'm at a loss here.

Comment: So is d.name NULL in the following query, or populated: `select j.name, j.owner_sid, s.name, d.name
from msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j
INNER JOIN master.sys.server_principals AS s
ON j.owner_sid = s.sid
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.sys.database_principals AS d
ON s.sid = d.sid;`

Comment: @AaronBertrand d.name is populated with `MyDomain\UserA`

Comment: Can you give some details about what the job does, what kinds of steps it has, any advanced options, that kind of thing? I'm guessing it has dependencies on databases that this login does *not* have access to...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Sure, however, the only reason I don't think that's relevant is that the same error occurs if I simply try to create a new job.

There are 3 job. Job one and two have one step (each) which is a CmdExec step. They both call scripts and there is nothing checked on the advanced tab.

Job three runs an SSIS package from the File system. It also has nothing checked on the advanced tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same exact problem - I had a new user which wanted to add jobs. I added this user to msdb db and added him to sqlAgentOperatorRole and db_datareader, db_datawriter. Still, when trying to add a new job, the user was getting the same error:

> Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "guest" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission. (Microsoft Server, Error: 15517)

I traced it down and it looks like when trying to add a new job (or doing many other things...) the following query is run:

```
exec master.dbo.sp_Msdbuserpriv 'serv'
```

So, obviously I had to add the new user to Master as well:

```
use master
create user [youNewUser] for login [yourNewUserLogin]
alter user [youNewUser] with default_schema=[dbo]
```

And now it works like charm...